# Image loads in vue3 frontend correctly from strapi api, but after page-reload or navigating it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: api, components, vuejs3, strapi, src

I'm fetching data in a dynamic route SingleProductView.vue:

```
{
  path: "/products/:id",
  component: () => import("../views/ProductSingleView.vue"),
},
```

After that I'm fetching the data from strapi in the template file:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import ProductSingle from "@/components/ProductSingle.vue";

let productDetails = ref({});
const route = useRoute();
const error = ref(null);
const url = import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPI_URL;

const apiUrl = url + "/api/products/" + route.params.id + "?populate=*";

onMounted(() => {
  fetchAllProductDetails();
  // console.log(productDetails);
});

const fetchAllProductDetails = async () => {
  await fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      productDetails.value = data.data.attributes;
    })
    .catch((err) => (error.value = err));
};
</script>
<template>
  <ProductSingle :product-details="productDetails" :url="url" />
</template>
```

From the parent template I'm sending the object with props to the child ProductSingle.vue. There I interpolate the given data:

```
<script setup>
import { useGetProductImage } from "@/composables/useGetProductImage";

defineProps({
  productDetails: Object,
  url: String,
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ productDetails.name }}</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>{{ productDetails.description }}</p>
    <hr />
    <p>{{ productDetails.price }}</p>
    <hr />
    <img :src="`${url}${productDetails.image.data.attributes.url}`" alt="" />
    <img
      :src="useGetProductImage(productDetails.image.data.attributes.url)"
      alt=""
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

I have a little composable useGetProductImage() that builds the link:

```
export function useGetProductImage(name) {
  const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPI_URL;
  return new URL(apiUrl + `${name}`, import.meta.url).href;
}
```

And it doesn't matter how I build my url-s in :src="${...}" AFTER RELOAD or NAVIGATING the site crashes with this error message:

[image]

Can anyone help please? :) I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

I tried building the link in 2 different ways, i tried saving the given data differently, but none of it worked. What I observed is that in the object lookup in the template if I'm looking deeper then 1 level - like productDetails.image.attribues.... object it gives the error again. :(

Comment: Did you tried to set `<div v-if="productDetails">` in your template? The one nesting the h2, p, img tags.

Comment: The reason being that you're fetching some data, it's not available from the start. But your template is sync, it expects everything to be there from the start. By doing a conditional, it will not crash because your template will take that into account rather than simply crashing as it does right now.

Comment: Yes, I tried v-if="productDetails and its not working if the image is included. Everything works fine untill I want to include the <img /> as well. I get all first level objects, but I cannot reach the ones that are nested deeper so like: productDetails.name ; productDetails.description ; productDetails.price is reachable, but productDetails.image.data.attributes is NOT :((

Comment: How do you fetch the one with `data`? Make a conditional on it in the same way, v-if...data...

Comment: This is quite unreadable. Please edit your question with that snippet highlighted please.

Comment: you can find it up in the second code block, in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Some days later I managed to  solve the riddle that caused the errors.

First of define a loading or isLoading boolean:

```
const loading = ref(null);
```

Then applying that in the fetch:

```
const fetchAllProductDetails = () => {
  loading.value = true;
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      productDetails.value = data.data.attributes;
      loading.value = false;
    })
    .catch((err) => (error.value = err));
};
```

Lastly conditionally rendering the component:

```
<div v-if="!loading">
  <ProductSingle :product-details="productDetails" :url="url" />
</div>
```